# Mouse wheel in VirtualPC (mostly) does not work on 64-bit Windows 7 RC

Tags: virtual-machines, virtualization, mouse

I have recently upgraded my laptop from WinXP Pro (32-bit) to Windows 7 RC (64-bit).  I have a number of VirtualPC 2007 images that I use for testing on various platforms and looking at beta software.  I have installed the 64-bit version of VirtualPC.  The images all work with the exception of the mouse wheel within the virtual machine.  I have tried this out with WinXP Pro, Windows 7 RC, and Windows Server 2008 images.  All are 32-bit and all exhibit the same behavior:  a gentle rotation of the wheel does nothing; a quick rotation of the wheel sometimes gets a scroll and sometimes not.  I regard this behavior as unusable as I tend to use the mouse wheel a lot.  All of this worked just fine on WinXP.  I have re-installed the Virtual machine additions on all of the machines.  The Windows 7 RC virtual image was created after the upgrade to Windows 7 and the 64-bit version of VirtualPC (just to isolate the possibility that I had corrupted the images during the transition).

I have googled, binged, and yahoo-ed.  There are scattered mentions of this problem (dating back to VPC 2004) but no solutions.

I am aware that I could start up one of these images and then use remote desktop connections to get access to that image.  I, in fact, do just that for some development that I am doing; the mouse works just fine.  This is acceptable in this case because I spend hours at a time in the development VM.  These test environments are different in that I will bring up an image for just a short time: minutes rather than hours.  Adding the rdc step is much more significant in these cases.

Does anyone have any idea of what to do next?

Comment: The Win7 RC is no longer available, supported, or recommended.

Answer (score 1):

Well windows 7RC is just an RC, after all. You can't reasonably expect that everything just works.

Answer (score 1):

It is a little confusing reading your post (always is with new releases of MS products).

Are you running "Windows Virtual PC" on your new workstation, and not "Virtual PC 2007"?

Comment: +1 Virtual PC 2007 is **not** support in Win7, he needs the Win7 version to start. Also using the Win7 RC isn't helping.